# CPU Speed stuck at 0.78 GHz, How do I increase it to its base speed of 2.30 GHz?

Tags: cpu-usage, hp-pavilion, intel-core-i5, cpu-speed, cpu-throttling

My 1yr old laptop, HP Pavilion 15 has it's CPU, Intel i5-8300H stuck at 0.78 GHz whenever it's plugged and charging, and the moment I remove the charger plug or switch it off, it increases suddenly and keep fluctuating freely, with good utilisation percentage more than 1-2GHz or more as I experience Thermal Throttling.

I tried sneaking into the BIOS to see if I can do anything, but found nothing. I also downloaded Intel Extreme Tuning Utility (XTU) but couldn't control it.

My question is how do I increase the speed to say atleast 2 GHz (fixed, not fluctuating) when it's charging, irrespective of getting thermal throttle, and also maybe even control the fan speed if it does get hot?

Comment: Left-click the battery icon while charging and see if you can change to "High Performance" or check your [power plan](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-change-power-plan-settings-windows-10-a.html) and make sure that it is not set to limit CPU while charging.

Comment: Please provide adequate information about your Power Plan settings

Comment: @Ramhound I tried all the available Power Plans and also some customized, but they didn't worked or had any effect whatsoever. The CPU frequency is locked with respect to the charging status. I am unable to find a way to toggle this setting anywhere.

Comment: I too had a similar problem on my HP.. my power supply was no longer providing the voltage my laptop needed so it would not throttle up.  I bought a new power supply.  I doubt this is your problem but something to consider.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug with Windows 10 20H2.

You will either need to rollback your latest update, figure out a way to install KB4580364, or wait for Microsoft to give you a fix using the regular update mechanism.

Here is a page confirming the problem:
https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-slow-cpu-frequency/

Here is the Microsoft page that shows ways to get the patch:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4580364/windows-10-update-kb4580364

PLEASE NOTE that this fix is still BETA (preview) software.  You need to ask yourself if you want to install another guess at a fix or roll back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, since I don't have any spare system PC, I'll wait for the official fix till then. I still haven't updated to the 2004 update yet, cause I read it's risky too.

Comment: @GeassDragon - It’s not dangerous. More users are on 2004 than any other version of Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem the last 2 times I upgraded windows 10 on my Lenovo X1 Carbon. The CPU is stuck at 0.78 Ghz.
This is the way I have fixed it these 2 times. (Last upgrade was to 20H2) I got this fix somewhere on the net. Don't know why it works.

1. Unplug the power.
2. Shut down the PC.
3. Restart the PC on battery power.
4. Plug the power back in.

After that, the CPU happily speeded up past the base frequency of 2.69 GHz, to 3 GHz and beyond as needed. This seems (for me) to be a permanent fix until the next Windows upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! For me it was enough just to unplug and plug-in again the power. No shutdown or restart was needed.

Comment: Unplug-plug also fixed the issue on my XPS 15.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 identical dell laptops with identical specs (i3-4005u, 4gb ddr3)

I noticed one day that whatever happened, the cpu clocks on one laptop won't go above 798 Mhz,

I tested both machines on different OSs for months without battery, so it wasn't a battery problem huh.

Then I tried switching the power brick from the one that worked fine to the one whose cpu won't ramp up, and it worked.

So I concluded that it was due to a powerbrick limitation it didn't work well. Both powerbricks for both laptops were bought from 3rd party vendors.

I hope this is helpful for anyone facing the same issue on laptop.

There are some other solutions you should try first,

Remove the battery and start on charger power and restart and install battery.

Also try disconnecting  the charger and reconnecting it, that worked too when I had installed battery in the laptop which had its cpu clocks stuck at 798 Mhz

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering this issue with my HP laptop.

What I did to fix it was by making sure I was updated to the latest BIOS on the HP website for my product, then resetting the BIOS to default settings.

If you are already on the latest BIOS for your laptop, then just go into the BIOS and reset settings to default.

Also, make sure to check for updates on Windows Update and HP Support Assistant. This issue seems to be quite a common bug with some HP laptops.

Comment: @LPChip - While I disagree about the helpfulness of the software in question.  It's clear based on the numerous questions about similar/exact behavior while running 20H2 this is a more widespread problem than a single device that isn't configured properly.  I suspect there is a cause for the behavior, it just has to be identified, might have to resort to Windows reddit.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree with the rest, just not that one should uninstall HP Support Assistant because it is OEM bloatware.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the exact same problem with Windows 10 and Windows 11 on a Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook. After Upgrading the BIOS to the newest version, some new options appeared. One was related to the power state of the CPU. This specific BIOS option allowed the Operating System to regulate the CPUs power states instead of the chipset. After disabling this option, the Processor worked just fine, turboing to over 3GHz and 100% CPU utilization when needed. For some reason, Windows seems to mess with the power states of specific notebook configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Update your system BIOS.

I had a similar issue with my Lenovo E580 laptop, running Windows 11 (22H2). Task Manager always reported CPU speed at 0.8 GHz. Changing power options had no impact.

Lenovo automatic update tool found a newer BIOS. After installing it (no reconfiguration) the clock speed behaved as it used to: It varies between 0.8 and 3.4 GHz, depending on system load.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you have tried this, but:

1. Right Click on the battery icon
2. Go to `Power Options`
3. Click on `Change plan settings` for the High Performance plan (if you don't have one, you can create one using the `Create a power plan` option on the left)
4. Under `Processor power management`:

   4.1. Set the `Minimum processor state` to 100%

   4.2. Set the `Maximum processor state` to 100%

   4.3. Set the `System cooling policy` to Active

Comment: Minimum processor state does not have to be 100%. Default value is 0%. Only the max should be 100%.

Comment: Yes, but they said they want the CPU clock to be at max value.

Comment: @Leopard20 thanks for the input but I have already checked this and it is exactly at those same settings which you replied here, or maybe I changed them this way before.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Windows 11.

Thanks to other answers I found a solution that hopefully might help you as well.

Go to `Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options` and switch from `Ultimate Performance` to `Balanced`. This did the trick for me.