# Ryzen 4600H CPU stuck at 0.39 GHz

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop, amd-ryzen

My 5 months old Lenovo Legion 5 laptop's CPU is stuck and locked at 0.39 GHz both in plugged-in state or battery mode. My brother was complaining of a serious throttling issue during his classes and when I checked the Task Manager, I found the CPU Clock stuck at 0.39 GHz. The BIOS version at this point was EUCN28WW and Windows Version: 20H2.

SPECS:

```
GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1650
CPU: AMD Ryzen 4600H
Motherboard: Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05 Type: 82B5
BIOS: EUCN31WW (upgraded from EUCN28WW)
OS: Windows 10 Home
```

Troubleshooting:

1. Tinkered with the Windows 10 power plan modes (Balanced, High Performance)
2. Changed the VANTAGE modes, Fn+Q
3. Tinkered with Windows 10 Min/Max Processor Power Management. Checked TEMP and FAN speed.
4. Unplugged the charger, held down the power the button for 45 seconds and then plugged in again
5. Applied factory reset within the system
6. Reset and updated the BIOS
7. Clean installation of windows 10 via USB pendrive (tried 21H1, 1909)
8. Updated all the drivers from the official website
9. Updated and uninstalled SYSTEM firmware, DEVICE firmware from DEVICE Manager.

[image: TaskMgr]

[image: Legion Pwr Mgmt]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infamous 0.39 GHz in Windows 10 issue has no fixes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes)

Comment: No, I have read and tried almost all the fixes mentioned above. The problem still persists. There's also a software named 'ThrottleStop' that fixes this issue in some of the Intel processors but mine Ryzen proc isn't supported. Kindly don't flag my question as a duplicate!

Comment: (1) Open up the computer and verify that all contacts are ok (pressing is good); use the opportunity to clean out the dust (carefully). (2) Try also running without the battery (if possible). (3) Try the solutions from [link](https://www.wintips.org/fix-cpu-not-running-at-full-speed-in-windows-10/) that you didn't try yet, (4) Disable in the BIOS features named like "Power Management",  "Enhanced Intel Speedstep Technology," "Enhanced C1," "Enhanced Halt State" or "Cool'n'Quiet".

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed this problem in my daughter's Inspiron laptop today. After trying all of the various "solutions" that I googled, I finally took a look at the AC adapter jack on the laptop. In the past, her 5 year old twin boys would play with the cord, and she said it sometimes didn't stay in properly.

Unlike many laptops that have a round jack with a center pin for the connection, the Dell has the round, 7mm jack, but the center has a black plastic cylinder with two pins in it. I noticed that the jack on my daughter's laptop had two thin pins in the jack but the plastic center piece was broken/missing.

After moving them around with a toothpick until they were near the center of the jack, I plugged in the ac adapter again and fired it up. Voila! CPU was now running at normal speed again. I searched on Amazon and found six or more listings for the short cable with the jack on one end, and a power connector on the other end. I ordered one for about $6.50 and it arrived today. Took about 10 minutes to replace it, and when I plugged in the adapter plug again, everything was perfect!

From what I saw, it appears that virtually every solution offered online neglected to suggest checking the jack itself - instead they suggested replacing the power brick. A few mentioned getting a new motherboard solved the problem, but of course that would be expected, as it would include a new jack.

Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: Ryzen 5 3750H here. Same problem. Did exactly what you've written. Solved my problem as well!

Answer (score -1):

My solution is unplug->plug all power cables including power brick, connector to laptop.
Also I plug-unplug some cable in USB type-C port on the right side of laptop, but don't know helps it or not.

Answer (score -1):

...here it solved the problem with unplugging the powercable for 2 seconds and plugging them in again. After doing it once, the cpu stays at full speed even though the temperature rises again over the barrier that led to the throttle to 0,39GHz before.