# Stuck at 0.39 Ghz: Lenovo Ideapad 5 with Intel i5-1135G7 processor

Tags: laptop, cpu, lenovo-laptop, cpu-throttling

**Description**

I bought the laptop in November 2021 and ran it with the pre-installed Windows OS, and had it running well on Windows 11 up until around January. Then suddenly, the CPU started throttling persistently, and task manager showed a reading of 0.39ghz. The laptop was slow as well to match that. When you boot the laptop, it initially runs at normal frequencies for around 30 seconds, and then suddenly, not with a gradient, drops to 0.39 ghz on every core. Some cores pop up to regular frequencies now and then, but it's overall very slow.

**What I tried**

First, I tried disabling the Intelligent Thermal Solutions Driver - didn't work. Tried reinstalling it - didn't work. Tried all the windows settings (performance mode, etc,. ) pertaining to the same - none of them worked. Tried using ThrottleStop to disable BD_PROCHOT, that didn't work either.

Then, I tried a BIOS update - got it to the latest version. That didn't work either.

**Linux**

Since the laptop was virtually unusable with those frequencies on Windows, I switched to EndeavourOS with XFCE - where I am currently typing this now. It's still slow with noticeable latency on most UI actions, but its 100x more usable.

On Linux, I tried setting the governor to performance, that didn't help either.

The problem is present when charging and on battery both, unlike a few other people online who I found that had similar problems.

**Hardware**

I noticed the temperatures - they are normal from whatever OS-level reading I can get.
I checked that the fans were running and they are.

I gave the laptop for general servicing where they changed the thermal paste, cleaned out the fans, etc,. That didn't help either.

**Voodoo**

I even tried a bunch of voodoo fixes - such as letting the battery drain out to the full and charging it again, disabling the battery in the bios and running on AC, that a few users online claimed worked for their system. That didn't help either.

*What else do I do?*

Comment: You will find another voodoo advice [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/WindowsOnDeck/comments/y8zdy6/anyone_bumped_into_this_issue_windows_11_cpu/).

Comment: Either *something* is overheating, or the BIOS is very confused. If using [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) and disabling `BD PROCHOT` helps then the firmware is telling the CPU that *something* is running hot and is limiting your system as a result. If you are absolutely 100% certain that absolutely every thermal sensor is reading low (including HDDs, SSDs and other devices) then it might be a firmware fault and a BIOS update might help.

Comment: Seems to be a common Windows issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1679451/ryzen-4600h-cpu-stuck-at-0-39-ghz and 
https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes . Look at power adapter plug, and be sure laptop is charging. Try another OS temporarily to see if it works at full speed, e.g., a Linux distro.

Comment: What is the health of the battery? Most laptops require the batter, in order to run at full performance, a battery with poor health, could result in the down clocking you describe

Comment: @Ramhound the battery is at around 85% health.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ryzen 4600H CPU stuck at 0.39 GHz](https://superuser.com/questions/1679451/ryzen-4600h-cpu-stuck-at-0-39-ghz)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infamous 0.39 GHz in Windows 10 issue has no fixes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes)

Answer (score 0):

Once I switched to linux, I didn't try disabling BD_PROCHOT as it didn't help when I tried it using ThrottleStop on windows.

However, disabling it with `msr` on linux has worked! I just need to disable BD_PROCHOT once on boot everytime, which I wrote a systemd service for, and the laptop's normal again.

Weirdly enough, if I enable it again after disabling it, it doesn't slow down again!

Here are the scripts for those interested
https://github.com/yyearth/turnoff-BD-PROCHOT

Thanks for the comments and pointers everyone!