# (Thinkpad Carbon X1 Gen 9) CPU @ 0.40Ghz when accessing via RDP for a while

Tags: cpu, remote-desktop, thinkpad

I have a carbon laptop that has a dead screen; it went out recently and I have decided to just leave the device around the house and occasionally remote into it, run some scripts from it, etc.

Well, I've noticed there's an issue with using it this way.

After being accessed via RDP for a while, it permanently clocks down the CPU to 0.40 - 0.93Ghz.

If I plug a monitor into it so i can actually access it directly, or sometimes if i just unplug and plug it in again while i'm on RDP, the clock speeds shoot up to 3.90-4.0Ghz.

But on RDP it inevitably drops back down to permanently 0.40Ghz.

I don't see an option in power options for the current power plan to set a minimum cpu state, so I don't know how to address this and tell it to stop clocking down the cpu, because clearly it thinks i'm afk / idle / not here when it's being accessed via RDP.

Comment: What is the current power plan?

Comment: The only option i have is 'Balanced'. I tried creating a new power plan, but the options i can configure within it seem very limited; it doesn't seem to have the usual options for the power plan details where you'd configure things like minimum cpu frequency

Comment: If you add the [Ultimate Performance](https://www.howtogeek.com/368781/how-to-enable-ultimate-performance-power-plan-in-windows-10/) power plan do you have more options?

Comment: This seems to be a common issue -- just search on "CPU stuck 0.39". For example: https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes,  https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/CPU-Clock-speed-stuck-at-0-39-Ghz/m-p/8320839 , Please feel free to answer your own question if you *do* find an answer!